# How best to integrate CiviCRM into our WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, hosting

Our website uses WordPress but the developers are having issues integrating CiviCRM.

Should we go elsewhere? We want integration with our website but can we do this hosting CiviCRM outside of the website?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Stackexchange, it might help if you include what issues the developers are having and what you are trying to achieve as it may be hard for other members of the community to offer any helpful advise otherwise.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you are hosting WordPress.

Comment: Paul you should respond to the requests for clarification - you're asking several questions but you haven't provided any information on your environment or the issues.

Comment: The website developers say: "We can spend some time investigating what's causing the issues in Wordpress when the plugin is active. Hopefully we would be able to figure out what's happening at that stage. After finding the cause of the issue, depending on the cause, we may be able to put a fix in place. The main problem with this path forward is that any fixes we make would likely require changes to the CiviCRM plugin files. As these files are maintained by Civi, any fixes we apply to the local copy of the plugin on your site are likely going to be overwritten in future updates."

Comment: You don't want them making changes to core civi files. If it is a conflict between civi and another WP plugin then yes such a conflict needs resolving. One option would be for you to get a dump of you WP site, give it to a civi developer, get them to provide a proper analysis and solution, and then give it back to your WP guys because, tbh, it would likely be both cheaper and longer-term to have a civi expert identify the problem

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of experience / skills they have.  There are a lot of Wordpress 'developers' that wouldn't be able to go fully into a web development role.

However they likely have no experience of CiviCRM so they will have to learn a new solution from scratch so there will be issues along the way.

If they are having issues they can reach out to the community for advise on how to bring it forward and resolve any issues they are having.

Answer (score 1):

Your title doesn't quite match the detail of the question. As Jade says it would help to have more detail, but answering the title question, I'd say that its an integration issue rather than an actual WordPress problem (many people run CiviCRM on WordPress successfully). So I'd say the website company needs to address the issues.

Looking at the more detailed question, it probably would be possible to host CiviCRM on WordPress elsewhere, but that isn't likely to make life easier. Your website developers are still going to have to integrate it into their site and you are also adding complexity by introducing a third party.

Comment: Yea, hosting CiviCRM in a location outside of where your Wordpress is located can indeed bring in more complexity and issues. It's why I've always kept them on the same server and hosting account.

Answer (score 1):

the answer may depend on how much you want to keep the WP developers involved in your WP site. Seem like several solutions eg

- change WP developer to one who can also support civicrm
- move hosting to a VPS so both your existing WP developers and a civicrm developer can have full access
- host your CiviCRM system 'somewhere else' and use eg Remote Forms to get your civi forms on your main WP site
- ask your existing WP developers if they can provide SSH access to a civicrm partner to take care of the installation